# The word 'sector' in Particle Physics

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, soft-question, beyond-the-standard-model

What exactly is meant when one uses the word [*sector*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sector) in Particle Physics?

As in, the [*Hidden Sector*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_sector) or the [*Electroweak Sector*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Electroweak_sector).

Does it refer to a specific part of the Lagrangian?

Or does it refer to the range of energies at which certain phenomena are expected / observed to occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term *sector* in quantum field theory typically refers to a portion of the Lagrangian. For example, in the Standard Model Lagrangian, we encounter a term,

$$\mathcal{L}_{SM}=(D_\mu \phi)^{\dagger}(D^\mu\phi)-\frac{m^2_h}{2v^2}\left( |\phi|^2-v^2/2\right) +\dots$$

plus others involving couplings with the Higgs doublet $\phi$, and we can refer to the subset as the *Higgs sector*. The *hidden sector* features all the interactions and terms in the Lagrangian which we expect exist, but have not explicitly written in the full Standard Model Lagrangian.

Answer (score 3):

Your first suggestion is correct, it refers to a part of the Lagrangian density. "Electroweak Sector" for example would refer to the part of the standard model Lagrangian relevant for the electroweak interactions.

Comment: so what's the Hidden Sector? It can't be in the Lagrangian can it?

Comment: @Harold: There is a Wikipedia article on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_sector

Comment: I know. And it says that it is 'collection of yet-unobserved quantum fields'.
So no Lagrangian?

Comment: @Harold: In principle all those fields should be in the Lagrangian. The problem is just that it is unclear at the moment what exactly this Lagrangian looks like.

Comment: so the only time the word 'sector' does not refer to a specific and known part of the Lagrangian is when we talk about the *Hidden Sector*?

Comment: Within the context of the standard model, yes.

Comment: @Harold The nicest way I found to think about it is the following: The $X$ sector refers to the part of the Lagrangian that specifies all $X$ interactions. This works for 'electroweak', 'Higgs', etc. but also for 'hidden'. The hidden interactions are simply those that we have not managed to observe yet, but that we *do* expect to exist.

Answer (score 0):

We can understand it from several points of view.

In the settings of Lagrangian formalism:

A ‘sector’ refers to a portion of the Lagrangian density.

Example 1. if we are studying a Lagrangian of the form
$$
\mathcal{L} = A_1 + A_2 + B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + C_1 =:\mathcal{L}_A+ \mathcal{L}_B + \mathcal{L}_C
$$
then we can say that the ‘A-sector’ is
$$
\mathcal{L}_A = A_1 + A_2
$$

In the settings of Hamiltonian formalism:

A ‘sector’ refers to a direct sum summand (do not confuse direct sum $\oplus$ with tensor product$\otimes$) of the Hilbert space of states.

Example 2. in Type 2 superstring theory we have the Fock space is
$$
F = ( NS\otimes NS) \oplus (NS\otimes R) \oplus (R\otimes NS) \oplus (R\otimes NS)
$$
We say that it has four sectors: (NS,NS) sector, (NS, R) sector, (R, NS) sector and (R, R) sector.

Example 3. In QFT, the Fock space for a single free field is
$$
F = \mathbb{C} \oplus H \oplus H^{\otimes 2} \oplus \cdots
$$
We say that $H^{\otimes n}$ is the n particle sector, and $\mathbb{C}$ the vacuum sector.

Again, do not confuse it with tensor product, which is the case of composing systems. For example, in CFT of string theory, the boson, fermion and ghost systems should form a tensor product, which justify the sum of three central charges:
$$
c_{boson} \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} 
 + \mathbb{I} \otimes c_{fermion}\mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} 
 + \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} \otimes c_{ghost}\mathbb{I} 
= ( c_{boson} +c_{fermion} +c_{ghost}) \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} 
$$
where we are computing sums of tensor products of operators, and $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the identity operator.